# HackerRank Scanner Class Java

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

this code is for printing linkedlist and Working fine in Eclipse:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HackerAss {
    static Scanner scan;
    static Node head;
    static Node current;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q=1,count=0;
        while(q==1){
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            q = scan.nextInt();
            if(q==0)
                break;
            else{
                int element = scan.nextInt();
                if(count == 0)
                    current = new Node(element);
                else{
                    head = new Node(element);
                    head.node = current;
                    current = new Node(element);
                }
            }

            count++;
            }
        while(head!=null){
            System.out.println(head.data);
            head=head.node;
        }

        }


    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node node;
        public Node() {
            data=0;
            node=null;
        }
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data=data;
            node=null;
        }

    }}
```

But in HackerRank it shows error :-

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Whats the reason of the error and whats the solution. I have Assignment to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem come from your code, not your IDE.

First, you should define a scanner once :

```
while(q==1){
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    q = scan.nextInt();  
    ...  
}
```

This is a really bad idea, beacause you don't even know if there is something in the stream, you had to use Scanner like this :

```
scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    q = scan.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

After, the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` come from the fact that you call nextInt() twice :

```
scan = new Scanner(System.in);
q = scan.nextInt();
...
int element = scan.nextInt();
```

In the doc `nextInt()` throw a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when the input is exhausted : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29

Answer (score 1):

This error comes out of nextInt(). You have to avoid this with a condition as below in the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HackerAss {
    static Scanner scan;
    static Node head;
    static Node current;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q=1,count=0;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(q==1){

            if(scan.hasNextInt() ) {
              q = scan.nextInt();
            }
            if(q==0)
                break;
            else{
                if(scan.hasNextInt() ) {
                  int element = scan.nextInt();
                }
                if(count == 0)
                    current = new Node(element);
                else{
                    head = new Node(element);
                    head.node = current;
                    current = new Node(element);
                }
            }

            count++;
            }
        while(head!=null){
            System.out.println(head.data);
            head=head.node;
        }

        }


    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node node;
        public Node() {
            data=0;
            node=null;
        }
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data=data;
            node=null;
        }

    }}
```

Comment: Also `scan = new Scanner(System.in);` should be moved out from `while` loop